# jekyll and sass; can i use the meta?

Tags: css, sass, yaml, jekyll

Say that I have a jekyll project that defines some data in _data/slides.yml:

```
- number: 1   
  image: image1.jpg   
  class: one
  paragraph: Apa

- number: 2  
  image: image2.jpg  
  class: two
  paragraph: Bepa
```

...etc

I then also have an include like so:

```
{% for slide in site.data.slides %}

  <!-- Section #{{ slide.number }} -->
  <div class="bg-wrapper">
    <div class={{ slide.class }} id={{ slide.class }}>
      <div class="page-bg"></div>
      <div class="center">
        <h1>{{ slide.number }}</h1>
        <hr>
        <h4>{{ slide.paragraph }}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

{% endfor %}
```

The idea is that there should be a section for every slide in slides such that the image in the slide is the background image.
Now, i know that i can add some inline style here with a class etc, but i'd rather loop through the data once more in my sass file and create a class for each. Is it possible to do something like that?

eg in main.sass:

```
---
---

{% for slide in site.data.slides %}

  .{{ slide.class }}
    background: url(/assets/images/{{ slide.image }}) no-repeat center center fixed

{% endfor %}
```

Further, if this is possible, can you also then pass the {{ slide.image }} as a parameter for a mixin?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The accepted answer shows it all. For me the problem was that i'm using .sass files (not scss) and didn't see my own mistake when i indented in the for-loop, causing sass to go ham.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it !

```
- number: 1
  image: image1.jpg
  class: one
  paragraph: Apa
  radius: 5px <-- added radius for example
```

**sass code**

```
@mixin border-radius($radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
     -moz-border-radius: $radius;
      -ms-border-radius: $radius;
          border-radius: $radius;
}

{% for slide in site.data.slides %}
.{{ slide.class }}{
  background: url(/assets/images/{{ slide.color }}) no-repeat center center fixed;
  @include border-radius({{slide.radius}});
}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Nice! Gonna try it out! Brb.